# IDL compilation doesnt return failure status

Tags: shell, idl-programming-language

I dont have much experience with IDL but i need to fix a bug where in the compilation failure status needs to be returned to the calling script.

```
    cat << ENDCAT > something.pro

    PRINT, "Start"

    PRINT, "Compiling functions needing early compile"
    @do_early_func

    PRINT, "Compiling remaining functions"
    @do_other_func

    PRINT, "Running: resolve_all"
    resolve_all

    EXIT

    ENDCAT

    setenv IDL_STARTUP something.pro

    $IDL_DIR/bin/idl
```

The above content exists in a script called *make_program* which is called by another script called the *build_script*

The problem i am facing is that even if 'resolve_all' results in a compilation failure, the *make_program* always returns a true to the *build_script* making it think the compilation succeeded when it actually didnt. How can i return the failure status back to the calling script?

Answer (score 0):

The `EXIT` routine has a `STATUS` keyword that can return the exit status of the script. So something like:

```
exit, status=status_code
```

To determine if `RESOLVE_ALL` completed correctly, you may need to do a `CATCH` block. The easiest way is probably to wrap `RESOLVE_ALL` in your own routine that has an `ERROR` keyword that returns whether the `RESOLVE_ALL` succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where I picked this up but you'll need two routines:

```
function validate_syntax_helper, routineName

  compile_opt strictarr, hidden

  catch, error
  if (error ne 0) then return, 0

  resolve_routine, routineName, /either, /compile_full_file
  return, 1

end
```

and

```
function validate_syntax, routineName

  compile_opt strictarr, hidden

  oldquiet = !quiet
  !quiet = 1

  catch, error
  if (error ne 0) then return, 0

  ; Get current directory
  cd, current=pwd

  o = obj_new('IDL_IDLBridge')
  o->execute, '@' + pref_get('IDL_STARTUP')
  ; Change to current directory
  o->execute, 'cd, ''' + pwd + ''''
  ; Validate syntax
  cmd = 'result = validate_syntax_helper(''' + routineName + ''')'
  o->execute, cmd
  result = o->getVar('result')
  obj_destroy, o

  !quiet = oldquiet

  return, result

end
```

You then call `validate_syntax`, which returns `1` when it can compile and `0` when it can't.  I don't think this can be used from the IDL virtual machine since it uses `execute`, but maybe that doesn't matter to you.  You'll have to manually run this on all your routines to be compiled instead of running `resolve_all`.